# Print the Curl output in bold in PHP

Tags: php, curl, fonts

Is there any way we can print the output of Curl in **bold** letters ?

My code is :

```
[insert_php]

$ch = curl_init("example.com");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

echo curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

[/insert_php]
```

`[insert_php]` as I am using wordpress .

Comment: This is not a PHP problem. The output gets handled by wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to add the  tag around the output. So you can change the echo line to something like this:

```
echo '<b>' . curl_exec($ch) . '</b>';
```